# Android - Facebook login with iOS Example

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I was wondering if anyone had an idea how to login with Facebook on Android? It was really simple on the iPhone but I'm noticing Android is a little more difficult. This is what I did on the iPhone, can anyone let me know what I need to do for android:

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"user_birthday", @"email"]
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:
     ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

         AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
         [appDelegate sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];


         if (session.state == FBSessionStateOpen)
         {
             //DO Action
         }
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an Android Facebook SDK that you can get here:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.0

enjoy!

Comment: This is using the Facebook login button, I'm trying to avoid using that. I just want to customize the action of the button.